# How do you start a session with cookies using redis with GraphQL?

Tags: typescript, redis, graphql

I am following along to [This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6ypD7qv3Z8) about setting up a full stack using GraphQL and React and have found myself stalled when trying to make cookies work.

Here's my index.ts

```
import { MikroORM } from "@mikro-orm/core";
import "reflect-metadata";
import { __prod__} from "./constants"
import microConfig from './mikro-orm.config'
import {ApolloServer} from 'apollo-server-express'
import {buildSchema} from 'type-graphql';
import { HelloResolver } from "./resolvers/hello";
import { AdsResolver } from "./resolvers/ads";
import { UserResolver } from "./resolvers/user";
import { Campaign } from "./entities/ads";
import connectRedis from 'connect-redis';
import { MyContext } from "./types";
import session from 'express-session';
import cors from 'cors';
import { createClient } from 'redis';
import express from "express";



const main = async () => {
    const orm = await MikroORM.init(microConfig);
    // await orm.getMigrator().up();

    const app = express();
    const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);
    const redisClient = createClient();


    app.use(cors({
      origin: ["https://studio.apollographql.com", "http://localhost:3000"],
      credentials:true,
    }))
    app.use(
      session({
        name: 'qid',
        store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient, disableTouch: true }),
        cookie: {
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10, // 10 years
            httpOnly: true,
            sameSite: "none",
            secure: __prod__,
        },
        saveUninitialized: false,
        secret: 'ezrtxhrdyugitryu',
        resave: false,
      })
    )

    const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
        schema: await buildSchema({
            resolvers: [HelloResolver, AdsResolver, UserResolver],
            validate: false,
        }),
        context: ({req, res}): MyContext => ({ em: orm.em, req, res })
    });

  await apolloServer.start();
    
  apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app, cors: false});

  app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Server start'));
};

main();
```

And my userResolver

```
import { User } from "../entities/users";
import { MyContext } from "src/types";
import { Arg, Ctx, Field, Mutation, ObjectType, Query, Resolver } from "type-graphql";
import argon2 = require('argon2');

@ObjectType()
class FieldError {
    @Field()
    field: string;
    @Field()
    message: string;
}

@ObjectType()
class UserResponse {
    @Field(() => [FieldError], {nullable: true})
    errors?: FieldError[]
    @Field(() => User, {nullable: true})
    user?:User
}

@Resolver()
export class UserResolver {
    @Query (() => User, {nullable:true})
    async me(@Ctx() { em, req}: MyContext) 
    {
        if (!req.sessionID)
          return null;
    
    const user = await em.findOne(User, {username: req.sessionID})
        return user;
    }
    @Mutation(() => UserResponse)
    async register(
        @Arg('username') username:String,
        @Arg('password') password:string,
        @Ctx() {em}: MyContext) : Promise<UserResponse>
        {
            if(username.length < 1)
                return {
                    errors: [{
                        field: "username",
                        message: "username invalid"
                    }]
                }
            const hashedPass = await argon2.hash(password);
            const user = em.create(User, {username: username, password: hashedPass});
            await em.persistAndFlush(user);
            return {user};
        }
    @Mutation(() => UserResponse)
    async login(
        @Arg('username') username:string,
        @Arg('password') password:string,
        @Ctx() {em}: MyContext): Promise<UserResponse> {
        const user = await em.findOne(User, {username: username});
            if(!user) {
            return {
                errors: [{
                    field: "username",
                    message: "user not found"
                }],
          }
        };
          const valid = await argon2.verify(user.password, password);
          if (!valid)
          return {
              errors: [
                  {
              field: "password",
              message: "incorrect password",
                  }
              ]
          }
          return { user };
        }
}
```

The suggested codes to be added to login mutation, `req.session.userId = user.id` `req.sessionID = user.username` or `req.session.id = user.id` do not work. I suspect this tutorial may be out of date in some way or I may have missed something, but the end result is the same : I can't get my damn cookies to work ! Could someone provide a solution ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you know that the cookie is not sent ? Are you checking in graphqlplayground ? Il yes, make sure to set the `credentials = include`  in the playground. And in the login mutation, make sure also to add the data in the `@Ctx()` session   `context.req.session!.User = User; `

`

Comment: I know the cookie isn't sent because it doesn't appear in my cookies on my broswer. `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` is indeed set to true in the playground. Also, `User` doesn't exist in my `req.session`. @Jerome

Comment: have you set the User in the graphql context in your login mutation as I mentionned in my previous comment? Can't see in the piece of code you've showed us

Comment: check NETWORK response headers [login mutation request] for cookie (or use Postman for the same) ... work on API until it contains a cookie